# plotnine - mapping variable to scale_color_gradient

Tags: colors, histogram, plotnine

I am trying to plot a histogram with a color scale from blue to white.

```
gg = pd.DataFrame()
gg['x'] = u
p = ggplot(aes(x='x'),gg) + 
geom_histogram(aes(fill='..count..'),binwidth=0.1)
p = p + scale_color_gradient(low='blue',high='white')
print(p)
```

If I comment out the scale_color_gradient line everything works with the default color scheme.

However, if I run the code above as is, I get the message:

UserWarning: Cannot generate legend for the 'color' aesthetic. Make sure you have mapped a variable to it
  "variable to it".format(output))

I have searched the documentation and examples but didn't find how to map the variable to the color scale.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mapped to the `fill` aesthetic with `fill='..count'`, so you should use `scale_fill_gradient`.